# If an algorithm runs in theta time, is it possible for there to be a function that is little o and little omega as well?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

If an algorithm runs in theta time, is it possible for there to be a function that is little o and little omega as well?

I am aware that if the function has theta time, then it implies it has a big o and omega function as well.

If it is possible, can you give an example of one.

Comment: `is it possible for there to be a function that is little o and little omega as well?` You mean, if it is `Theta(f(n))`, is there *any* g(n),h(n) such that it is also `o(g(n))` and `omega(h(n))`, if so - yes. `Theta(n^2)`, and `o(n^3)`, `omega(n)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there can't be one such function both in little o and little omega at the same time.

Say your function is `f(x)`. Then for little o  `f(x) ∈ o(g(x))` follows `g(x)` grows much faster than `f(x)`. Similarly, if  `f(x) ∈ ω(g(x))`, follows `g(x)` grows much slower than `f(x)`.

Therefore:

> o(f) ∩ ω(f) = ∅.

However, for Theta:

> f(x) ∈ Θ(g(x)) iff f(x) ∈ O(g(x)) and f(x) ∈ Ω(g(x))

So for `f(x) ∈ Θ(g(n))`, `f(x)` **must** be both in `Ω` and `O` of `g(n)`.

It might be also easier to grasp, if you remember that little `o` is the  **inverse** of little `ω`. Hence

> f(x) ∈ o(g(x)) <=> g(x) ∈ ω(f(x))

As a side note, little `o` and `ω` are rarely used in Computer Science. Most algorithms run in Big `Θ`, `O` or `Ω`.